# Command to sum 2nd colum of csv file

Tags: bash, awk

hi i have a csv file which has 2 coloumns first column has names and secons has values. All i want is a script that can sum values of second column and print output in last row of csv as Total

example of file:-

```
CNG 2128485188
WND 222047363
HUM 283010928
AINGO   253694944
```

The command i am using is printing in last line but giving total as 0.

```
$ awk '{print;s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}' /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/SCCP_ADMIN_RAW2.csv | tail -10
LIMIT,27789
VDEOT,21109
CELZA,627
DUUNI,26636
EMBLT,1255927
URA,521
MONTE,1789
EGLMO,391
DGTEL,394
Total 0
```

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print;s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}'

Comment: still giving total as 0

Comment: $ awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print;s+=$2}END{printf "Total %'\''d\n",s}' /cygdrive/c/KPI/
test/SCCP_ADMIN_RAW2.csv | tail -10
LIMIT,27789
VDEOT,21109
CELZA,627
DUUNI,26636
EMBLT,1255927
URA,521
MONTE,1789
EGLMO,391
DGTEL,394
Total 0

Comment: my fault. It is the separator problem. It is comma, the default is space.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"," '{print;x+=$2}END{print "Total " x}' ./test.csv 
CNG ,1
WND ,2
HUM ,1
AINGO   ,1
Total 5
```

Comment: what if i want comma "," after "Total" ?

Comment: awk -F"," '{print;x+=$2}END{print "Total ," x}' ./test.csv

Comment: If you want to save it in CSV file add in the end: > filename.csv

Comment: @dngot_ How can I give the column number as a variable? eg: `colNo=2` and I want to give this `$colNo` variable to this awk command

Comment: `awk -F"," '{print;x+=$colNo}END{print "Total " x}' ./test.csv ` This does not work

Comment: I found the solution at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-bash-passing-variables-to-awk/